# Libgdx Palette Swap

Tags: libgdx, palette

I'm developing a game using the Libgdx library.

I'm trying to implement a very simple palette swap functionality (basically just complete recolouring of some areas, I don't even need to have various shades), but I don't have any idea where to begin.

The closest I've come is trying to draw the picture myself using a Pixmap, but that appears to be horrible unmaintainable and produces oodles of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you have already tried, but you can simply get the Pixmap of the Texture and draw over it:

```
texture.getTextureData().prepare();
Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
for(int i=0; i < pixmap.getWidth(); i++)
{
  for(int j =0; j < pixmap.getHeight(); j++)
  {
    if(pixmap.getPixel(i,j) == colorToReplace)
    {
      pixmap.drawPixel(i,j,newColor); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar to yours and it worked well. The getPixel returns an integer representing the colour in rgb888 value. Otherwise it worked for my case.  Thanks